# Upgrading from Rails 2.3.8 to 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running an application on Rails 2.3.8. I am planning to upgrade it to Rails 4.0 (which is in RC). What will be the easiest way for me to do this? Do I need to first upgrade to Rails 3.x?

Note: in my current implementation, I am using starling and ferret; as part of upgrade I am also considering to move to [sidekiq](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/sidekiq) and [sunspot](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/sunspot)

Comment: "Do I need to first upgrade to Rails 3.x" - that depends on your threshold for acceptable pain :).  In general, breaking up large changes into smaller incremental changes is a recommended approach.

Comment: Also, you should certainly try to upgrade to the latest 2.3.x before moving to either 3.x or 4.

Comment: you will most probably need to upgrade your ruby as well

Comment: I really hope you have a decent test coverage before you dive into that. Even a non-decent coverage will help keep your heart rate within a healthy range.

Answer (score 51):

This is a multi-step process, and depending on the size of your application, it can take a long time. At each step, you'll want to test your application for bugs and problems and broken gems (because they are most certainly going to crop up). I have included links for the most complicated steps. Here is the path of least pain:

Update to Rails 2.3.18.

[Update to Ruby 1.9.3.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915222435/https://eng.uservoice.com/blog/2012/03/04/how-to-upgrade-a-rails-2.3-app-to-ruby-1.9.3/)

[Update to Rails 3.0.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625112247/http://railsdispatch.com/posts/upgrading-a-rails-2-app-to-rails-3)

- [Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1)
- [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2)
- [Part 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3)

[Update to Rails 3.1.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-0-to-rails-3-1)

[Update to Rails 3.2.latest.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2)

Update to Ruby 2.0.latest.

[Update to Rails 4.0](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4).

[Update from Rails 4.0 to Rails 4.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-0-to-rails-4-1).

[Update from Rails 4.1 to Rails 4.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-1-to-rails-4-2).

[Update from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-2-to-rails-5-0).

[Update from Rails 5.0 to Rails 5.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-0-to-rails-5-1).

Bonus: If you have a large application, this is going to take a long time. If you have a large team, long-running branches become a huge headache because of recurring merge conflicts. One strategy for mitigating this is to [dual boot your application with both versions of Rails](http://shayfrendt.com/posts/upgrading-github-to-rails-3-with-zero-downtime/) so that you can have the new version running on your master branch, rather than on a long-running branch of its own.

Comment: Hi. Just out of interest, why do you upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 before upgrading to Rails 3.0? Rails 2.3 doesn't support Ruby 1.9 out of the box, whereas Rails 3 does, so does this approach create additional work to make Rails 2.3 work with Ruby 1.9?

Comment: Good point. You can definitely upgrade to Rails 3 before moving to Ruby 1.9. In our case, we had a large application, and moving from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9 was far less work than moving from Rails 2.3 to 3.0.  It took us a couple months to get on 1.9, but over a year to get on 3.0. So, we went with the easier update first to give us the performance benefits and gem compatibility of Ruby 1.9 sooner.

Comment: OK, interesting. I had wondered if going to ruby 1.9 first might be the right thing to do for performance reasons - hadn't considered gem compatibility. I'll try the rails upgrade first and see how I get on.

Comment: To follow up here, I upgraded the whole way through to latest Rails 3.2 under Ruby 1.8.7, but I found the performance was so bad that I had to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 anyway before going to production. So I would recommend upgrading to Rails 3.0 first, then Ruby 1.9.3 (for gem compatibility and performance benefits mentioned by @aaron), and then rails 3.1, 3.2.

Comment: Links to guide lead to 404's

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've updated the two dead links to use the Wayback Machine so they can be accessed again.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron Gray's answer is very useful, but sometimes it's very difficult after upgrading to find the differences between rails version in the code. I mean, many times after upgrading something doesn't work. Maybe could be some changes in the file or some file could be added or removed in newer version. There is a nice tool, how you can find out all differences between version and compare them. It's on [Rails differences](http://railsdiff.org/) and could be very helpful to discover some potential mistakes and bugs.