# How to upgrade rails 2.3.12 to 3.x or 4.x versions using JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I used Jruby version 1.6.5.1 which include Ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.12. and gem 1.6.2.
How can I upgrade all this versions to higher versions (Jruby 1.7.x, ruby 1.9.x or 2.x and rails 3.x or 4.x)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141363/upgrading-from-rails-2-3-8-to-4-0 Is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rvm` to [manager ruby version](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

Bellow code lines is use install `ruby 1.9.3` on Centos. You can refference it.

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

rvm install 1.9.3

rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Comment: nvm? what is it ? rvm might be

Comment: sorry missing type. yes, you can try use `rvm` to manager ruby version

Answer (score 0):

this will be a multi-step process and largely depends on the gems you're using. it really helps if you happen to have test coverage, otherwise it might get a little painful.

here's shortly what I would do (did some 2.3 upgrades previously) :

- upgrade JRuby to latest 1.7.x it defaults to 1.9.3 but using --1.8 makes it 1.8.7 compatible
- setup Bundler on Rails 2.3 http://bundler.io/v1.11/rails23.html (will help managing the gems)
- attempt to upgrade to Rails 3.2 (review an empty created app to adjust the environment/*.rb, environment.rb, boot.rb etc. accordingly) - some gems might need an upgrade or replacing
- switch off the --1.8 switch for JRuby ... you'll be running with 1.9.3
- (optional) upgrade to Rails 4.x
- (optional) upgrade to JRuby 9.0.x

*each step assumes running tests or somehow testing out the app is in a working state.