# how to run rails 2 project on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fedena

hey I want to run the fedena project (that is actually on rails 2) on rails 4. Any idea how can I do that. Do i have to update the app using rake app:update or something else. please help me out. I can't find a proper solution. Thanks

Comment: Many changes in Rails 4 arent backward compatible. I am afraid you will have to migrate the app to Rails 4.

Comment: There are upgrade guides available for rails but these are usually incremental. Unlikely you will find one that will take you straight from 2 to 4. What you are undertaking won't be an easy process ... you might want to start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141363/upgrading-from-rails-2-3-8-to-4-0/17641442 and also check out the rails site on upgrading (though that doesn't cover prior to version 3) : http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html (incremental upgrade guides are on the right). I would recommend that you only upgrade if you have good test coverage.

Comment: Write test cases for all the features. Then slowly upgrade individual gems.